# Can I disable macOS Sierra's sticky window edges?

Tags: window-manager, macos

In macOS Sierra, the window edges are sticky and grab the edges of the display, the top of the Dock and the bottom of the menu bar when being moved around.

This is very useful most of the time, but sometimes I would like to disable it. Whilst it is possible to move the window away from the edge and move it back again which seems to override the sticky edge functionality, I'd like something to prevent the initial grab in the first place.

Is there a way to disable macOS Sierra's sticky window edges?

Comment: Searching for an answer to this took me to [this blog](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/all-the-little-things-macos-sierra-hidden-features/) :-)

Comment: sooooooooooo has anyone figured out the terminal libraries switch for this? I agree with the comment about "live with it or stop using macOS" but given the programs I use lynx would just be a headache (more than the snapping) and windows... well nope. any news would be greatly appreciated, if not thanks to OP of showing me I am not alone

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hold down option when dragging. Will disable "sticky" edges as needed, when needed, without disabling it all the time by default.

Comment: is there a way to disable it all the time as the default? I never want the sticky behavior.

Comment: Not that I have seen. It's one of those "live with it or stop using macOS" kind of decisions made by Apple.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to override the sticky edge:

- Move the window faster. There is a speed threshold after which the sticky effect won't take place.
- After the edge sticks, simply keep moving in the same direction. The window will unstick. No need to move back and then forward again.
- As mentioned in the question, move back and forth.
- As mentioned in another answer, hold the option key while dragging.

Answer (score -2):

Applying the option 'Keep Folders on top when sorting by name', in Finder's Advanced Preferences section appears to work for me.

Comment: This seems to make no difference to me; I'd even say it'd be a bug if it did, since the option is in Finder preferences rather than system-wide and would appear to be a completely unrelated setting, making no mention of window positioning. Could you perhaps add a gif to your answer demonstrating the difference you're seeing between the option being enabled and disabled?